# Android send SMS to multiple contacts using ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, sms

Im writing an app that sends an SMS to several contacts. The contacts numbers are stored in an `ArrayList` (was received from another activity). I am not able to use this `ArrayList` to pass several contacts to the built-in SMS android app. This is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersArrayList=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("phoneNumbers");
String message= "this is a custom message";
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
smsIntent.putExtra("address", ??????????);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

I can iterate and print these contacts to the LogCat the simple "for each" loop and overriding toString method.

Comment: Check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065910/sending-sms-programmatically-to-multiple-people-getting-generic-error

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276712/sending-sms-to-multiple-contacts-using-loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code..

```
String toNumbers = "";
for ( String s : numbersArrayList)  
{  
    toNumbers = toNumbers + s + ";"
}  
toNumbers = toNumbers.subString(0, toNumbers.length - 1);
String message= "this is a custom message";

Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + toNumbers);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sendSmsTo);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the app crashes, ive copied several lines from the log:
05-27 15:38:46.208: E/AndroidRuntime(981): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 15:38:46.208: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.example.appofthecentury.CreateEventActivity$5.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:111)
05-27 15:38:46.208: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-27 15:38:46.208: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)

Comment: to concatenate with ";", you could do this instead of a loop :
String toNumbers = TextUtils.join(";", numbersArrayList);

Comment: hi Is there any limit defined by android for Contacts size?actually having more then 1000 contacts for sending sms. can it works for all thousands contancts on single send click?.