# Sending message to Multiple Persons using send intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use the android share intent from my application.

I have listed all the contacts from my contacts content provider in my application.
Now i want to send message to all the contacts i have selected(in my app) using any of the message app 
installed in user phone.

I do not want to user smsmaanger , simply want to user any sms sending application in user mobile if 
available.
I tried to do with email works great but not with sms .

I tried with email as  works great

```
public static void send(Context ctx, String[] addy, String subject,
        String body,File attachment) {
    try {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                addy);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                "Send via which Application?"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "No activity was found to handle this action",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For sms i am using like this .

```
public static void send(Context ctx, String addy, String subject,
        String body,File attachment) {
    try {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER,
                addy);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                "Send via which Application?"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "No activity was found to handle this action",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I just simply want to add my all contacts to users message app for sending message, with a message 
possible

Comment: Try the link pasted below.

[Send SMS to multiple contacts.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771470/android-send-sms-to-multiple-contacts-using-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send SMS to multiple numbers you need to separate the numbers with `;`
Sample here:

```
String toNumbers = "";
ArrayList<String> numbersArrayList;// your phone numbers here
for ( String number : numbersArrayList)  
{  
    toNumbers = toNumbers + number + ";"//separating numbers with semicolon
}  
toNumbers = toNumbers.subString(0, toNumbers.length - 1);// remove the last semicolon
```

...

```
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, toNumbers);
```