# Send SMS to multi users

Tags: android, sms, message

In my application,i have created an edit-text view and three buttons. When user clicks on "Add More Contacts" button, it will add another edit-text view and when user clicks "Add Contact" this will take him to contacts of phone-book from where he can choose the contacts to which he wants to send the SMS. I have written program for all this but i don't know how to send message to all users automatically without the user confirmation when he just pressed the "Send Message"Button. I tried SMSManager but its depreciated.Please suggest me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn_cntct;
    public int REQUESTCODE = 1;
    private LinearLayout layoutLinear;
    private Button btn_addmore_cntct;
    private int id = 1;

    Button b_alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
        btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
        btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
            }

        });
        // defining button and edit-text values for adding mutli edit-texts
        // views
        layoutLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
        btn_addmore_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddmorecontacts);
        btn_addmore_cntct.setOnClickListener(OnClick());
        EditText editview = new EditText(this);
        editview.setText("Add more");

    }

    // implementing OnClickListener OnClick() method for "btn_addmore_cntct"
    // button
    private OnClickListener OnClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // changing return type "null" to "new OnClickListner"
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                // setting id for edit-text views
                tab.setId(id);
                // and increment
                id++;

                // adding (0) to display edit-text view on the top
                layoutLinear.addView(tab, 0);
                tab.requestFocus();
                // for sending sms
                b_alert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.balert);
                b_alert.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String smsNumber = tab.getText().toString();
                        String smsText = "I am in danger";

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                        intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
                        startActivity(intent);               


                    }
                });

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // calling onActivityResult when contacts has been selected from the
    // phone-book, giving back the REQUESTCODE i started it with, the RC it
    // returned with
    // any additional data from it.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.i("data", uri.toString());
            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri,
                                    new String[] {
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                    null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(0);
                        String number = c.getString(1);
                        int type = c.getInt(2);

                        showSelectedNumber(name, number, type);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // defining showSelectedNummber to display selected contact from phone-book
    // to Edit-Text View
    public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String number, int type) {
        if (layoutLinear == null) {
            Log.i("layoutLinear is null", "null");
        } else {
            Log.i("layoutLinear is not  null", "not null");

        }

        EditText userNumber = (EditText) layoutLinear.getChildAt(0);
        if (userNumber == null) {
            Log.i("edittext is null", "null");
        } else {
            Log.i("edittext is not  null", "not null");

        }
        String typeNumber = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                .getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
        userNumber.setText(name + ": " + number + " " + typeNumber);

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14067178/2567598

Comment: not working ... SMSManager deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) with loop of **Numbers** you need to send

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("NUMBER",
                                null, "TEXT_TO_SEND", null, null);
```