# How to send sms to all numbers in ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-pendingintent

I have `ListView` which of it's items contains mobile numbers. Now I want to send SMS to all of them on a single `Button` click. `ListView` is populated by `CursorAdapter` from `Database`. And I also want to set `PendingIntent` to each `ListView` item. How to achieve it? please help. I have posted till what I have tried here. Thank you.

> XML for `ListView` item is

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/card_style">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username"
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mobile No."
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView24" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Serial No."
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView28"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView27" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView28"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="ON"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/btnStatusON"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_report"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> XML for `ListView` is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1d4563">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit"
    android:hint="enter Serial No. to search"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView13" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:src="@drawable/search"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioFilter"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All"
        android:id="@+id/radioAll"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activated"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/radioActivated" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not Activated"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/radioNotActivated" />
</RadioGroup>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/send_request"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioFilter"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText2" />
```

> `CursorAdapter` Class is

```
public class DisplayAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public DisplayAdapter(Context context,Cursor c){
    super(context,c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_items, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tvUserName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView27);
    tvUserName.setText(cursor.getString(2));

    TextView tvMobile=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
    tvMobile.setText(cursor.getString(3));

    TextView tvSerail=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
    tvSerail.setText(cursor.getString(5));
}
}
```

> Activity file is

```
public class TableBikeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DisplayAdapter adapter;
private SearchDisplayAdapter adapter1;
private statusAdapter adapter2;
ListView bikeList;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
EditText myFilter;
ImageButton search,imgSendStatus;
RadioGroup radioFilter;
SmsManager smsManagerBike;
Button statusButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_bike);

    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    bikeList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    bikeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView textSrNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
            String srNo = textSrNo.getText().toString();

            String selectQuery = "select * from bikeTable where uSerialNo='" + srNo + "'";
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String strUser = cursor.getString(1);
            String strMobile = cursor.getString(2);
            String strAddress = cursor.getString(3);
            String strSerialNo = cursor.getString(4);
            String strImei = cursor.getString(5);
            String strCimi = cursor.getString(6);
            String strDeviceNo = cursor.getString(7);
            String strDealerCode = cursor.getString(8);
            String strDealerContact = cursor.getString(9);

            cursor.close();

            String strTest = strUser + "#" + strMobile + "#" + strAddress + "#" + strSerialNo + "#" + strImei + "#" + strCimi + "#" + strDeviceNo + "#" + strDealerCode + "#" + strDealerContact + "#";

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("details", strTest);
            Intent bikeIntent = new Intent(TableBikeActivity.this, BikeReport.class);
            bikeIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(bikeIntent);
        }
    });

    int[] colors = { Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3") };
    bikeList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllDataBike());
            bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

    search=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageView13);

    myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String strFilter = myFilter.getText().toString();

            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (strFilter.equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(TableBikeActivity.this,"Please Enter Valid Serial No.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllDataBike());
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        adapter1 = new SearchDisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.searchCustomerBike(strFilter));
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            final String strFilter = myFilter.getText().toString();

            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (strFilter.equals("")) {
                        adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllDataBike());
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        adapter1 = new SearchDisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.searchCustomerBike(strFilter));
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    radioFilter=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioFilter);

    radioFilter.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId==R.id.radioAll){

                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllDataBike());
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }else if (checkedId==R.id.radioActivated){

                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getActivated());
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }else if (checkedId==R.id.radioNotActivated){

                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter = new DisplayAdapter(TableBikeActivity.this, databaseHelper.getNotActivated());
                        bikeList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    smsManagerBike=SmsManager.getDefault();
    imgSendStatus=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    imgSendStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            String query="select userName, mobileNo, uSerialNo, uContactNo from bikeTable WHERE mobileNo IS NOT NULL AND vehicleType='Two Wheeler'";
            final Cursor statusBikeCursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

            if (statusBikeCursor.getCount()>0) {

                while (statusBikeCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String userName=statusBikeCursor.getString(statusBikeCursor.getColumnIndex("userName"));
                    final String userNo=statusBikeCursor.getString(statusBikeCursor.getColumnIndex("mobileNo"));
                    String serialNo=statusBikeCursor.getString(statusBikeCursor.getColumnIndex("uSerialNo"));
                    String deviceNo = statusBikeCursor.getString(statusBikeCursor.getColumnIndex("uContactNo"));

                    final String date= DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new java.util.Date());
                    final String dte=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

                    //starting of pending intent setting//

                    statusButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStatusON);

                    final String SENT="sent";
                    String DELIVERED="delivered";

                    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TableBikeActivity.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
                    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TableBikeActivity.this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

                    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            switch (getResultCode()){
                                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

                                    cv.put("sent", "1");
                                    String where="mobileNo='"+userNo+"' AND sentTime='"+dte+"'";
                                    db.update("statusTable",cv,where,null);

                                    statusButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_sent);
                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    },new IntentFilter(SENT));

                    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            switch (getResultCode())
                            {
                                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                                    cv.put("delivered","1");
                                    String where="mobileNo='"+userNo+"' AND sentTime='"+dte+"'";
                                    db.update("statusTable",cv,where,null);

                                    statusButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_delivered);
                                    break;
                                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    },new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

                    //end of pending intent block//

                    smsManagerBike.sendTextMessage(deviceNo, null, "?", sentPI, deliveredPI);

                    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                    try{
                        cv.put("userName",userName);
                        cv.put("mobileNo",userNo);
                        cv.put("serialNo",serialNo);
                        cv.put("deviceContact",deviceNo);
                        cv.put("sentTime",dte);

                        db.insert("statusTable", null, cv);
                        Toast.makeText(TableBikeActivity.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }catch (SQLiteException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(TableBikeActivity.this,"Table Creation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(TableBikeActivity.this,"No Device is Activated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065910/sending-sms-programmatically-to-multiple-people-getting-generic-error

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What isn't working? What is happening?

Comment: Actually this problem producing part has been ruled out of my project @DavidWasser